# Perform Singular Value Decomposition of (2 0 1;0 1 0)

Tags: matrices

I've got the questions to perform a singular value decomposition for the matrix  **A = (2 0 1;0 1 0)**. I know the method and calculated it to be,

A = PDQ, where

**P = (5 0;0 1)**

**Q = (1/sqrt(5)).(2 0 -1;0 1 0;1 0 2)**

**D = (sqrt(5) 0 0; 0 1 0)**

my only issue is when I put it back into the equation where A = PDQ, I dont get the original matrix back, can someone figure out which one of my 3 variables are wrong? Or if im just being silly

Thanks

Comment: You need to calculate $PDQ^T$. Also, $P=I_2$.

Comment: See the way they teach it to me at uni is PDQ, but enter Q as row vectors instead of column, this is so when calculating the pseudoinverse we can do A+ = P(T)D+Q(T)

Comment: IM SO SILLY, my P was wrong, no idea how I got 5 0 for the first row, dont think i divided by anything